# No Gold and Silver for me!

Tags: support, badges

I can only see Bronze badges available for me:

[image]

Gold and Silver badges are nowhere to be seen:

[image]

[image]

Why is that? Is there any criteria to pass, for them to be visible?

This applies for both SO and Meta SO.

Comment: You clicked the link to track a *tag* badge, there is a different button for tracking normal badges. It's in the centre *"Badges"* section.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two kinds of badge in Stack, tag badges and all other badges.

Tag badges are earned for getting a score on a particular tag, for instance you currently have a score of 52 from 65 posts on C#

[image: Poster's tag score]

To get a bronze tag badge you'd need a score of 100 from at least 20 posts so you fulfil one of the criteria but not the other.

You will only see silver tag badges to track when you have that tag's bronze badge, and similarly you'll only see a gold badge when you have the corresponding silver tag badge. Since you don't have any bronze badges you're not able to see any silver or gold in the tracker.

You can track your progress towards your next privilege instead of a tag by changing the dropdown (see the image below) and you can track normal (non-tag) badges using the "Next badge" button (circled in red in the screenshot). If you run out of privileges, you can only track tags.

[image: badge tracking]